# Is it possible to compress JSON object in memory

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I would like to keep in memory medium size JSON file from hard disc (it have 14mb). I found easy way to do it:

```
 public static void Load(string path = CacheFilePath)
    {
        path = Path.GetFullPath(path);
        if (!File.Exists(path))
            return;

        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        using (FileStream s = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open))
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
        using (JsonReader red = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            while (red.Read())
            {
                JObject Data = serializer.Deserialize<JObject>(red);
            }
        }
    }
```

And everything is working but, this JObject take almost 360mb RAM. Is it possible to set any JSON setting to reduce this value?

or maybe there is another way to keep data as JSON in memory?

Quick look on file (example, real have something about 230 k):

```
{
    "OrderValidationData":
    {
        "Count":2,
        "Name":"OrderValidationData",
        "Keys":[
            "WAL22999-96",
            "HEL5DA 193 175-111", 
            **n**
        ],
        "Data":
        {
            "WAL22999-96":
            {
                "MinimalNetPrice":10.00,
                "VatRate":12.00
            },
            "HEL5DA 193 175-111":
            {
                "MinimalNetPrice":10.00,
                "VatRate":12.00
            }
            , **{n}**
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it help to store it (deserialize it) as a "real" object instead of a JObject?

Comment: Try to follow this recommendations https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReducingSerializedJSONSize.htm

Comment: Thanks!, I checked both suggestions but unfortunatly this "real" object is also JSON :) so I have no option to change it. I checked recommended link but official site contains tips only how to reduce memory space only for C# class object. In this case I don't have specified class (this is a reason why I deserialize object on JObject). But I'll keep looking for solution

Comment: You might see if any of the suggestions from [Newtonsoft json.net JsonTextReader Garbage Collector intensive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55839493/3744182) help.

Comment: Do you have the option of using .net core 3.0 and System.Text.Json API? That is supposed to be both faster and cause less allocations for read access.

Comment: Have you considered other serializers, e.g. ProtoBuf?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no option to upgrade use .net core (project working on 2.0). I've never heard about ProtoBuf, but I'll check this option

Comment: You might check to see whether deserializing to `ExpandoObject` gives a smaller memory footprint.

Comment: Lucas have you got any solution?

Comment: Nope, to be honest this task wasn't so important and I decided to don't change a json library (Newtonsoft).