# Caching/interning object keys when deserialising JSON with Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, string, json.net, deserialization

I have an API method that loads ~100k rows from a DB into memory and each of these rows contain a JSON string. For each request, the JSON object structure will be the same (same object keys) across all of the rows, although I will not know this ahead of time.

At the moment I am calling `JObject.Parse(row.Json)` for every row to get a JObject. When I examine the heap, I can see a duplicate entry for every single object key string. So if I have the object key `id` in the JSON of each row and I have 100k rows, I see 100k instances of this string in memory.

I would like to cache (or potentially `String.Intern()` depending on lifetime) these object keys and reuse the strings in these `JObject`s. I can see that using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` I can supply a custom converter, but AFAIK they let you modify the JSON values and not the keys.

Note: I must have all 100k rows in memory at a time as I later run an algo that requires everything at once.

Comment: Sounds like you need a different structure in memory; convert from your list of "objects" to a set of arrays... you could parse the first row for an array of keys, then all rows could be parsed into JSON arrays, `[key1,key2,key3]` `[ [r1c1val],[r1c2val],[r1c3val], [r2c1val] ...`

Comment: Related: [Newtonsoft json.net JsonTextReader Garbage Collector intensive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55812343/3744182).  `AutomaticJsonNameTable` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55839493/3744182) may be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the structure of the JSON, you could always create a class that contains the most common fields. This will save quite a bit of space.

```
class RowData
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("anyOtherFixedField")]
    public string OtherField{ get; set; }
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public IDictionary<string, JToken> ExtraProperties {get; set;}
}
```

The fields that have a property will not have a string on the heap at all.

Any fields in the JSON that doesn't have a corresponding property will go into the `ExtraProperties` dictionary.

Comment: Sadly, there are no such common fields across requests, only within a single request will the objects look the same, but I wouldn't know their structure at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a good way to hook into the default JObject deserialization.

I've made a custom converter, based on the provided [`ExpandoObjectConverter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/ExpandoObjectConverter.cs), that creates a `JValue`/`JObject`/`JArray` instead of an `ExpandoObject`. All object keys are cached and reused for the lifetime of the converter.

To use this converter, you have to specify that you want to deserialize to a `JToken`,`JObject` or `JArray`.
If you don't specify a target type, this converter will not be used.

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(json, new NameCachingJObjectConverter());
```

And the implementation.

```
public class NameCachingJObjectConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // can write is set to false
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return ReadValue(reader);
    }

    private JToken ReadValue(JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (!MoveToContent(reader))
        {
            throw new Exception("Unexpected end of content");
        }

        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.StartObject:
                return ReadObject(reader);
            case JsonToken.StartArray:
                return ReadList(reader);
            default:
                if (IsPrimitiveToken(reader.TokenType))
                {
                    return new JValue(reader.Value);
                }

                throw new Exception("Unexpected token when converting object: {reader.TokenType}");
        }
    }

    private static bool IsPrimitiveToken(JsonToken token)
    {
        switch (token)
        {
            case JsonToken.Integer:
            case JsonToken.Float:
            case JsonToken.String:
            case JsonToken.Boolean:
            case JsonToken.Undefined:
            case JsonToken.Null:
            case JsonToken.Date:
            case JsonToken.Bytes:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    private static bool MoveToContent(JsonReader reader)
    {
        JsonToken t = reader.TokenType;
        while (t == JsonToken.None || t == JsonToken.Comment)
        {
            if (!reader.Read())
            {
                return false;
            }
            t = reader.TokenType;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private JArray ReadList(JsonReader reader)
    {
        var list = new JArray();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.Comment:
                    break;
                default:
                    object v = ReadValue(reader);

                    list.Add(v);
                    break;
                case JsonToken.EndArray:
                    return list;
            }
        }

        throw new Exception("Unexpected end when reading JObject.");
    }

    private JToken ReadObject(JsonReader reader)
    {
        var expandoObject = new JObject();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.PropertyName:
                    string propertyName = GetCachedName(reader.Value.ToString());

                    if (!reader.Read())
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Unexpected end when reading JObject.");
                    }

                    var v = ReadValue(reader);

                    expandoObject[propertyName] = v;
                    break;
                case JsonToken.Comment:
                    break;
                case JsonToken.EndObject:
                    return expandoObject;
            }
        }

        throw new Exception("Unexpected end when reading ExpandoObject.");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether this instance can convert the specified object type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="objectType">Type of the object.</param>
    /// <returns>
    ///     <c>true</c> if this instance can convert the specified object type; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </returns>
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (typeof(JToken).IsAssignableFrom(objectType));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether this <see cref="JsonConverter"/> can write JSON.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     <c>true</c> if this <see cref="JsonConverter"/> can write JSON; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public override bool CanWrite => false;



    private string GetCachedName(string value)
    {
        string ret;
        if (!cache.TryGetValue(value, out ret))
        {
            cache[value] = value;
            ret = value;
        }
        return ret;
    }
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> cache = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```